Android Cuttlefish - Using swtpm with crosvm (launch_cvd) on Debian without TPM
I have a Debian 12 system without a TPM. Using launch_cvd on this host fails to start the VM:
$ HOME=$PWD ./bin/launch_cvd --verbosity=VERBOSE
.
.
.
secure_env detected guest reboot, restarting.
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_Startup
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_DictionaryAttackLockReset
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
File gatekeeper_secure was empty.
Initializing secure index file
File gatekeeper_insecure was empty.
Initializing secure index file
Resource allocated
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_CreateLoaded
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_HMAC
Received TPM response tpm:warn(2.0): the TPM was not able to start the command (2338)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_HMAC
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Freeing resource
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_FlushContext
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
.
.

(this enters a restart loop)
A successfull boot on a machine with a TPM looks like this:
.
.
secure_env detected guest reboot, restarting.
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_Startup
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_DictionaryAttackLockReset
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Resource allocated
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_CreateLoaded
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_HMAC
Received TPM response tpm:warn(2.0): the TPM was not able to start the command (2338)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_HMAC
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Resource allocated
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_CreateLoaded
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Resource allocated
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_Load
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_EncryptDecrypt2
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Freeing resource
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_FlushContext
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Freeing resource
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_FlushContext
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Freeing resource
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_FlushContext
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Restoring index from file
Resource allocated
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_CreateLoaded
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_HMAC
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Resource allocated
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_CreateLoaded
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Resource allocated
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_Load
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_EncryptDecrypt2
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Freeing resource
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_FlushContext
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Freeing resource
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_FlushContext
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Freeing resource
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_FlushContext
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
starting Rust KeyMint TA implementation in a thread
starting C++ KeyMint implementation in a thread with FDs in=32, out=31
KeyMint Rust TA running with infile=38, outfile=37, security_level=Software
Secure deletion data file found. Parsing.
Receiving oemlock command
Received message with id: 3
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_Read
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending oemlock response
Receiving oemlock command
Received message with id: 3
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_Read
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending oemlock response
Receiving oemlock command
Received message with id: 3
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_Read
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending oemlock response
[INFO  casimir] Incoming NCI connection from 127.0.0.1:46212
[INFO  casimir] Accepted NCI connection from 127.0.0.1:46212 in slot 0
Failed to connect:No such device
Receiving oemlock command
Received message with id: 3
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_Read
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending oemlock response
Receiving oemlock command
Received message with id: 3
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_Read
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending oemlock response
Receiving oemlock command
Received message with id: 3
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_ReadPublic
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending TPM command TPM2_CC_NV_Read
Received TPM response tpm:success (0)
Sending oemlock response
.
.

How can I use a vTPM in a cuttlefish VM started with launch_cvd?
